# How to call Index View with parameter of any MVC5 controller via anchor tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, anchor

I have a Mvc controller

```
public class ApplicationsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Applicants/Applications
        public ActionResult Index(Guid? ApplicationId)
        {
           //some work with the ApplicationId
            return View("Application Details");
        }


    }
```

There is an anchor tag in my another HTML page through which I want to call this controller default view(index view). The URL should be :

http://localhost:66666/Applicants/Applications/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I'm trying to call it via an anchor tag :

```
 <script id="applicationDetailstemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
<a href="../../../Applicants/Applications/{{:id}})">{{:position}}</a>
 </script>
```

the url comes proper but the action never gets called. If i remove the id from anchor tag, the controller view gets called but the ApplicationId is null. How can I pass the id as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect, unless you've changed your default routing rules, that you need to write it as

```
../../../Applicants/Applications?ApplicationId={{:id}}
```

Normally the form where you put the ID into the path (as opposed to the querystring) only works if the variable in your action method's signature is literally just "id" (not any other name).

Also if this is part of a View, consider using a HTML helper to ensure that the correct URL is always generated for the main part of your path, e.g.:

```
@Url.Action("Applicants", "Applications")?ApplicationId={{:id}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Adyson 
thank you for the answer. actually i knew the answer you gave but in url I didnt wanted the extra applicantId to appear. so I tried and I found out that :

1) `<a href="../../../Applicants/Applications/Index/{{:id}}">{{:position}}</a>` calls the Index view with the Id getting passed. but in url Index will come.

2)  `<a href="../../../Applicants/Applications">{{:position}}</a>` Default Index view can be called via this method and url will be http://localhost:66666/Applicants/Applications

3) `<a href="../../../Applicants/Applications/{{:id}}">{{:position}}</a>` this will not work no matter what .

finally i ended up renaming the index view to detail view and settled down. still got to know cant call index without it appearing in the URL with Id being passed into the view.